# Specman-e: Generate all possible solutions?

Tags: specman

When re-generating a particular structure is there an easy way to make it not generate a previous value until all possible values satisfying the constraints have been generated?

For example, when (re)generating:

```
Start as:
  specman -c 'define TRIES 16; load x;run;' 

<'
struct x {
    data[2] :  list of uint(bits:2);
};
extend sys {
    fu : x;

    run() is also {
        for i from 1 to TRIES do {
            gen fu;
            print fu.data;
        };
    };
};
'>
```

There are a possible `4*4 = 16` combinations of data and the question is about being able to `gen` 16 times and get 16 different values.

Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, just found `<list>.is_all_iterations` but unfortunately it only works on scaler fields and I have a list of constrained size as a field to be iterated over.

Comment: In you case it's probably preferential not to use generation but to just iterate over the possibilities.

Comment: Thanks Thorsten. I am coming to the same conclusion myself after searching the language spec :-)

Answer (score 2):

all_different() can help here. It's a bit tricky, because the field is a list. So this can be done using an auxiliary field. For example:

```
struct x {
    data[2]     :  list of uint(bits:2);

    data_as_one :  uint(bits:4);

    keep data[0] == data_as_one[1:0];
    keep data[1] == data_as_one[3:2];
};

extend sys {
    fu : x;

    fus[TRIES] : list of x;
    keep fus.all_different(.data_as_one);

    run() is also {
        for each in fus {
            out(it.data);
        };
    };
};
```

Comment: THanks for this. Unfortunately it will not work in my case as to simplify my question I used a fixed size for data where in truth, its size is a constraint and can change between runs. I don't know how to do your `keep data[..] == data_as_one[..];` for varying data.size()? - But thanks again :-)